# label's text flashing in windows form in C# by click on a button for a given time interval

Tags: c#

i want to write a windows form application in c# with bellow features:

the form has a button, a text in a label and a timer.

when i click on the button the text will disappear until the time that the timer shows that. then the text will be appear again after that elapsing time.

for example : the timer value=10000 milliseconds, so by clicking on the button the text will disappear for about 10000 milliseconds and will be shown again after that time.

how can i write the program?

Comment: To get the best response from people on SO you need to show that you have made some effort yourself - not treat SO as a code writing service. You should show the code you have written so far & explain exactly why it does not work.

Comment: Show the code you have so far. What issue are you having?

Comment: yes you're right. but i'm new to programming and also new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically on button click, you start the timer and hide the text. Then after 10000ms the timer ticks, it stops itself and you show the text.

In code this would look something like this:

```
    string labelText;

    private void yourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelText = yourLabel.Text; // Save it
        yourLabel.Text = ""; // Hide the text
        yourTimer.Start();
    }


    private void yourTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourTimer.Stop();
        yourLabel.Text = labelText;
    }
```

This code assumes you have set the events (Double-Click on the controls in the designer).

~Twometer

Comment: But actually you should not just ask "how can i write this program" because StackOverflow isn't a community that writes code for you. You should tell us what you have done so far and what problems you ran into etc

Comment: thanks. i tried it. it works
sorry i'm new to stackoverflow. many steps are remaining to become an expert ;)

Comment: Nice it worked for you. Tip for becoming an expert: Accept an answer with the green check when it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a timer to your form
2. Modify interval property of your timer
3. In function ticks of your timer do it:

> ```
> private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>   label1.Visible = true;
>   timer1.Stop();
> }
> ```

4. In your button click function

> ```
> private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         label1.Visible = false;
>         timer1.Start();
>     }
> ```

Comment: thanks. you taught me how to use properties in c# . 
:)